# ttysXXX in who command

Tags: macos, mac

I am just playing with my OS-X terminal.
When I use the command: `who`
It result with the following output:

```
raj   console  Sep  3 09:37
raj   ttys000  Sep 11 16:58
raj   ttys002  Sep 11 17:53
raj   ttys004  Sep 11 17:53
```

I'm confused with what is meant by ttys000, ttys002 & ttys004?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everytime you open up a new terminal window it's allocated a "pseudo teletype" aka ptty.  When the os needs to send some info to one windows, it just specifies the ptty it's going to get sent to.

You'll notice that as you open and close terminal windows, the number of lines listed there will grow and shrink.

That's it!

Comment: What does `s` in ttys stand for?

Comment: @Pacerier use `man ttys`  =  `ttys -- terminal initialization information`

Comment: @JayRizzo the description from the `man ttys` command doesn't even have an `s` character. I bet it's plural like `tty` is teletype and `ttys` is for teletypes.